# Error in python code, not sure how to solve it?

Tags: python, selenium, automation, webdriver, syntax-error

I am using selenium with webdriver for login on a particular website but got stuck in the middle. The error comes when it starts to type email address.

Code is below:-

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://society6.com/login?done=/")
username = driver.find_element_by_id('email').click()
username.send_keys("exp4money@gmail.com")
password = driver.find_element_by_id('password').click()
password.send_keys("abcd")
button = driver.find_element_by_name('login').click()

Error - username.send_keys("exp4money@gmail.com")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
```

the mouse is clicking on the textbox but its not typing
what mistake am i doing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error means, that the `username` has the `None` value.

That in turn means, that your command

```
username = driver.find_element_by_id('email').click()
```

returns `None`.

Why?

Because the `.click()` method returns `None`.

So, split that command into these two:

```
username = driver.find_element_by_id('email')
username.click()
```